# Problema de iniciante no JS, preciso mostrar uma certa quantidade de números positivos e negativos

Tags: javascript

Preciso mostrar 1 valor positivo e 3 negativos, sendo os valores {-5,0,-3,-4,12} porém dá um erro onde o código lê que todos os valores são positivos ou negativos. Já tentei outros códigos porém eles também não funcionavam.

O código:

```
let valoresPares = 0;
let valoresImpares = 0;
let valoresPositivos = 0;
let valoresNegativos = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const valorInformadoPeloUsuario = parseInt(gets());

  // TODO Criar a condição adequada para verificar se o "valorInformadoPeloUsuario" é par.
  if (  valorInformadoPeloUsuario %2 == 0  ) {
    valoresPares++;
  } else {
    valoresImpares++;
  }

  if (  2 === 0) {
    valoresPositivos++;
  } else if (  2 !==0) {
    valoresNegativos++;
  }

}

console.log( valoresPares + "par(es)");
console.log( valoresImpares + "impar(es)");
console.log( valoresPositivos + "positivo(s)");
console.log( valoresNegativos + "negativo(s)");
```

Comment: O que você acha que vai acontecer na comparação `if (  2 === 0)`? Não deveria ser `if (valorInformadoPeloUsuario > 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

O erro está nesta estrutura condicional:

```
 if (2 === 0) {         // false
    valoresPositivos++;
 } else if (2 !== 0) {  // true
    valoresNegativos++;
 }
```

- O JavaScript recebe **false** neste primeiro operador relacional, porque 2 não é igual a 0. Entretanto, ele recebe **true** no segundo operador, pois 2 é diferente de 0.
- Desta forma, o seu código vai sempre incrementar na variável **valoresNegativos**.
- Exemplo de resolução:

```
let valoresPares = 0
let valoresImpares = 0
let valoresPositivos = 0
let valoresNegativos = 0

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const valorInformadoPeloUsuario = parseInt(gets())

  // TODO Criar a condição adequada para verificar se o "valorInformadoPeloUsuario" é PAR
  if (valorInformadoPeloUsuario % 2 == 0) {
    valoresPares++
  } else {
    valoresImpares++
  }

  if (valorInformadoPeloUsuario > 0) {
    valoresPositivos++;
  } else if (valorInformadoPeloUsuario < 0) {
    valoresNegativos++;
  }
}

console.log(valoresPares + " par(es)")
console.log(valoresImpares + " ímpar(es)")
console.log(valoresPositivos + " positivo(s)")
console.log(valoresNegativos + " negativo(s)")
```